# Writing helper and helper_spec in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have written the following helper for sending email for my controller:

```
module SendEmail
  def send_mail(subject, body)
    to = "abc@gmail.com.com"
    cc = "def@gmail.com" 
    html_message = %{<html><body>body</body></html>}
    flag1 = system %{echo "#{html_message}" | mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -s "#{subject}" #{cc} -- #{to}}
  end
end
```

Where should I place this module such that controller can use that?

Where should I place the rspec code for the same? How do I write rspec-test case for this? How do I test `mutt` for this helper?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing helper methods w/ RSpec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508464/testing-helper-methods-w-rspec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you put it in `app/controllers/concerns`

you test `mutt` by factoring out the call into a helper method that creates the command and test that one. you can also stub or mock the `system` call. i would not test mutt directly, as an external resource, it should be properly configured using some configuration tool like chef.

Comment: How do I stub/mock the mutt call? Can you please look at this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513679/mocking-stubbing-system-call-using-rspec