# Mocking/stubbing system call using RSPec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

This is helper module:

```
module SendingMailHelper
  def send_mail(subject, body)
    to_email_id = " abc@gmail.com"
    cc_email_id = "def@gmail.com"
    html_message = %{<html><body>#{body}</body></html>}
    flag=false
    while(!flag) do
      flag = system %{echo "#{html_message}" | mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -s "#{subject}" #{cc_email_id} -- #{to_email_id}}
    end
    flag
  end
end
```

The way I have written my spec is as follows, but it is not working:

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper')

describe SendingMailHelper do
  it "test something" do
    html_message = %{<html><body>www.google.com</body></html>}
    to_email_id = " abc@gmail.com"
    cc_email_id = "def@gmail.com"
    subject = "test e-mail"
    SendingMailHelper.expects(:system).with(%{echo "#{html_message}" | mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -s "#{subject}" #{cc_email_id} -- #{to_email_id}}).returns(true).once
    helper.send_mail("test e-mail","www.google.com").should==true
  end
end
```

Getting the following error:

```
SendingMailHelper test something
     Failure/Error: SendingMailHelper.expects(:system).with(%{echo "#{html_message}" | mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -s "#{subject}" #{cc_email_id} -- #{to_email_id}}).returns(true).once
     Mocha::ExpectationError:
       not all expectations were satisfied
       unsatisfied expectations:
       - expected exactly once, not yet invoked:
```

**I also want to mock it in such a way that mocked mutt returns `false` twice and true in the third call to test the retry mechanism. Is there a way to do that?**

Comment: Try `Kernel.expects(:system)...`

Comment: How should I fix the above test-case?

Answer (score 0):

```
require_relative './sending_mail_helper'
require 'rspec/mocks/standalone'

describe SendingMailHelper do
  let(:helper) do
    Class.new do
      include SendingMailHelper
      attr_reader :system_calls

      def system(*args)
        @system_calls ||= []
        @system_calls << args
        [false, false, true][(@system_calls.size - 1) % 3]
      end
    end.new
  end

  it "test the call is made" do
    html_message = %{<html><body>www.google.com</body></html>}
    to_email_id = " abc@gmail.com"
    cc_email_id = "def@gmail.com"
    subject = "test e-mail"
    helper.send_mail("test e-mail","www.google.com")
    # check it was called once
    helper.system_calls.size should eq 1
    # check it was called with appropriete arguments
    helper.system_calls.last.first.should eq %{echo "#{html_message}" | mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -s "#{subject}" #{cc_email_id} -- #{to_email_id}}
  end

  it "retries the command until it succeded" do
    helper.send_mail("test e-mail","www.google.com")
    helper.system_calls.size.should eq 3
  end
end
```

You could use this little hack. Actually this is pretty much what stub and mocks do to monitor function calls.Trying to run the tests using the rspec-mock facilities failed badly.Personally I would advise you not to test the system calls it actually brings a lot of coupling in your tests and implemetation and makes the code harder to maintain.Another advise i would give you is using some ruby gem to handle the email functionalities you are trying to achieve insted of using sys calls to commands.Finally sorry for the use of `shoulds` but i have old rspec gem on my computer and the new `expect` syntax is missing.